# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'JOB'

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I run the Function manually in Oracle 11g, I am getting the    below error.

> Error starting at line 1 in command: Error report:
>   ORA-06550: line 22,
>    column 8: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>    'JOB'
>   ORA-06550: line 22, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Code which I am running is:

```
DECLARE
     xyz                          config_jobs.id%TYPE;
     p_daemon_host_name           managed_devices.host_name%TYPE;
     p_target_device_id           managed_devices.id%TYPE;
     p_target_device_host_name    managed_devices.host_name%TYPE;
     p_target_device_ip_address   managed_devices.ip_address%TYPE;
     p_type                       daemon_job_types.key%TYPE;
     p_set_of_files               set_of_files; -- for config download
     p_plugin_name                config_collection_classes.name%TYPE;
     p_plugin_date                config_collection_classes.timestamp%TYPE;
     p_plugin                     config_collection_classes.class%TYPE;
     p_reason                     VARCHAR2(200); -- 'M'anual, backup before/after 'U'pdate,'S'cheduled collection
     p_username                   config_jobs.username%TYPE;
     p_ft_key                     file_types.key%TYPE;
     p_oids                       set_of_oids;
     p_properties                 BLOB;
     p_max_thread_count           job_daemons.max_threads%TYPE := NULL;
     p_current_thread_count       job_daemons.current_threads%TYPE := NULL;
     p_jd_version                 job_daemons.version%TYPE := NULL;
BEGIN
     xyz := device_job.job(p_daemon_host_name,p_target_device_id,p_target_device_host_name,p_target_device_ip_address
    ,p_type,p_set_of_files,p_plugin_name,p_plugin_date,p_plugin,p_reason,p_username,p_ft_key,p_oids,
     p_properties,p_max_thread_count,p_current_thread_count,p_jd_version);
END;
```

Main Function in my package `Device_job` is as below:

```
 FUNCTION job (
     p_daemon_host_name           IN managed_devices.host_name%TYPE,
     p_target_device_id           OUT managed_devices.id%TYPE,
     p_target_device_host_name    OUT managed_devices.host_name%TYPE,
     p_target_device_ip_address   OUT managed_devices.ip_address%TYPE,
     p_type                       OUT daemon_job_types.key%TYPE,
     p_set_of_files               OUT set_of_files,        -- for config download
     p_plugin_name                OUT config_collection_classes.name%TYPE,
     p_plugin_date                OUT config_collection_classes.timestamp%TYPE,
     p_plugin                     OUT config_collection_classes.class%TYPE,
     p_reason                     OUT VARCHAR2,        -- 'M'anual, backup before/after 'U'pdate,'S'cheduled collection
     p_username                   OUT config_jobs.username%TYPE,
     p_ft_key                     OUT file_types.key%TYPE,
     p_oids                       OUT set_of_oids,
     p_properties                 OUT BLOB,
     p_max_thread_count           IN job_daemons.max_threads%TYPE := NULL,
     p_current_thread_count       IN job_daemons.current_threads%TYPE := NULL,
     p_jd_version                 IN job_daemons.version%TYPE := NULL
) RETURN config_jobs.id%TYPE IS
```

Comment: Why are you creating a `Function` with an `OUT` paramater. A `Function` in general returns a value and using `OUT` parmater doenot make more sense even though you can use it. Just replace your `FUNCTION` with `PROCEDURE` and remove `return`.

Comment: Replace `:= NULL` with `DEFAULT NULL` or completely remove it from the Function definition. On another note - XING is  completely right, just make xyz one of the OUT parameters, remove the return clause and call it a `PROCEDURE`.